# Can't change type of a column from string to DateTime in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I have a simple model that represents a movie

```
public class Movie
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Genre Genre { get; set; }
        public byte GenreId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string DateAdded { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int NumberInStock { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to change type of `ReleaseDate` and `DateAdded` to `DateTime`, so at first I try to do it only for the `ReleaseDate`

```
public class Movie
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Genre Genre { get; set; }
        public byte GenreId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string DateAdded { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int NumberInStock { get; set; }
    }
```

Aftet this I add a migration and try to update my database, but it gives me this error

> The object 'DF__Movies__ReleaseD__5441852A' is dependent on column 'ReleaseDate'.
>   ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN ReleaseDate failed because one or more objects access this column.

I have already changed a type of a column from `string` to `DateTime` in another model, so it's possible.

How do I fix this error and why it occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to enable migrations?

Run the Enable-Migrations command in Package Manager Console

This article might help you:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx